# How to execute command on ConEmu through VB.Net?

Tags: windows-8, conemu, vb.net

Did anybody know how to execute command on ConEmu through Vb.Net? This is the code that i tried for command prompt, and it works well. But when i tried on changing the cmd.exe to ConEmu.exe, it does not execute my "script.py". That's all. Thanks.

```
 Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Shell("cmd.exe /k python script.py")

        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

 End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

If you type `ConEmu64 /?` at the command prompt it'll bring up a dialog which explains how to do this thoroughly. I think the command you are wanting would look like this:

```
ConEmu64.exe /noupdate /cmd cmd /k python script.py
```

or, perhaps:

```
ConEmu64.exe /noupdate /cmd python script.py
```

Comment: Still, if this app is intended to be distributed then I'd just stick with cmd.exe because you don't want to require ConEmu to be installed for your users.

Comment: it's just for my personal use. Thanks for your answer, will try it out